# How to move a website from shared hosting to VPS?

Tags: migration, plesk

Because of resource and performance problems I want to move my website from Shared hosting to VPS. In this process, I also want to migrate from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.4. Therefore I need to re-code the PHP scripts. So I need time for my own on the new Plesk server to get things done.

I have the next steps in mind:

1. Create the webspace with the domain name on Plesk.
2. Upload the sources and database to the VPS.
3. Install an SSL certificate on the new site.
4. Add the domain name to the hosts file.
5. Re-code and test the new site.
6. Change the DNS to the new IPs.

There is a deadlock situation, however.

1. I can not issue a new SSL certificate without changing the DNS.
2. I can not migrate and test the site without an SSL certificate.

Of course, this is done before by many developers, but how it's done?
Does anyone know? And which other problems can I expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purchase a wildcard certificate or create one by letsencrypt
And use a subdomain like test.yourdomaine
And point it to your reverse proxy vps new ip

Comment: Ok, and when I go live? How to remove the subdomain?